# Is it possible to use a YN467 TTL Flash Speedlite on a Nikon D40?

Tags: flash, nikon-d40

I am considering the purchage of a YN467 TTL Flash Speedlite for Nikon D700/D300/D200/D90/D80/D5000: but I need to use it on a Nikon D40.

Although I have been told that it can work, I want to be sure before I purchase it. If it works, are all the functionality present or are in any way reduced?

Answer (score 1):

[speedlight.net](http://speedlights.net/2010/09/10/yongnuo-yn-467-speedlite-review/) reports at the end of this review that there are two versions, one with plastic and one with metal shoe. Perhaps the reason for the confusion about this is that one works and one doesn't?

I would send a message to the manufacturer to find out for sure.

[e-bay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/YN-467II-TTL-Flash-Speedlite-Nikon-D40X-D40-D90-D60-D70S-/180899736523) reports a model "YN467" that does work, but it is shown in later pictures as the "YN467II". Maybe this 2nd version is the one you are looking for, as it has stated support for the D40.